# Binary XML File Error Inflating RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-cardview

I keep getting this error:

```
Binary XML file line #11: Error inflating class androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
```

I have gone through many responses on this website but I am yet to rectify this issue. I have added the new implementation amongst other things. Any help received would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Error Code

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{rslpf.pa.myapplication/rslpf.pa.myapplication.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #11: Error inflating class androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2325)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #11: Error inflating class androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:633)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:743)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:555)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:161)
    at rslpf.pa.myapplication.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:32)
```

please find my XML File portion below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">



<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView

    android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Gradle Dependencies:

```
dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.0'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.1'

//implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.1.0';
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@android:color/primary_text_dark is color selector, you should replace to your color, not use color selector, same

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">
    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView

        android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: The colour selector usually works normal for me. Anyway, the change did not help me

Comment: It means you can use color, not a selectorColor

Comment: Ok, understood but do you have any other recommendations to help me solve this?

Comment: You can use any color other, same #ff0000 to set background RecyclerView

Comment: Ok. I deleted the background tag to verify this and I can say that it worked. The selectorcolor usually pops up on its own but never gave an issue. Thanks for the assistance.  I will try #ff0000 to see if the error comes again or if I should just remain without background.